# Get user role value from Enum

Tags: java

I use this Enum for available user roles types:

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT;

  public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
  }
}
```

Full code: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/JwtTokenProvider.java#L50)

But when I try to convert the list using this code:

```
claims.put("auth", roles.stream()
                        .map(s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s.getAuthority()))
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

I always get NPE when I try to get `s.getAuthority()`. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: First filter out nulls, then map values using non-nulls. In other words swap order of `map` and `filter`.

Comment: You need to call a name with one of your values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove all the null values with `filter` before using `map`.

```
roles.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .map(s -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(s.getAuthority()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```